# Linear Regression Analysis where both independent and dependent variables are binary indicator variables - Interpretation/Model

Tags: r, regression, logistic, model

I trying to model the probability of a women having received a mammogram in the past year (MAMHAD1YR). This variable is 0 or 1. Where 1 indicates that they have received a mammogram and 0 indicates that they haven't. All of my explanatory variables are either binary indicators, or categorical (range from 1-3). HISPETH (1 for hispanic, 0 for not), CITIZEN(1 for non-citizen, 0 for citizen), POORYN(1 for below the poverty line, 0 for above), EDUC (1 for no HS, 2 for HS, 3 for degree). I've included the outputs from the linear regression below.

I'm not sure what types of plots or how I would go about visualizing the data if I have no continuous variables. I have been told that a continuous variable is something I should look at including in my model, but no variables in this data set would be useful to me (I'm using the NHIS data from IPUMS). The years in this data set only ranges from 2011-17 and age is only from 30-80.

Do my results, or variables that using, indicate that I should look into using some sort of other regression method? Like a Logit model? Or is this type of regression analysis still valid? Also, some assistance interpreting my results would be helpful, thank you.

```
Call:
lm(formula = MAMHAD1YR ~ HISPETH * CITIZEN + POORYN + EDUC, data = data_clean, 
    weights = PERWEIGHT, family = "binomial")

Weighted Residuals:
   Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 
-81.18 -24.82 -10.77  27.27  94.39 

Coefficients:
                 Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)      0.324884   0.006468  50.233  < 2e-16 ***
HISPETH         -0.021580   0.005896  -3.660 0.000252 ***
CITIZEN         -0.162852   0.010084 -16.150  < 2e-16 ***
POORYN           0.117616   0.004779  24.612  < 2e-16 ***
EDUC             0.021922   0.002480   8.838  < 2e-16 ***
HISPETH:CITIZEN  0.070849   0.014363   4.933 8.12e-07 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 27.39 on 95936 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.01549,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.01544 
F-statistic:   302 on 5 and 95936 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```